# h264 real time video streaming

Tags: c++, html, video, ffmpeg, streaming

If you have dynamically generated **h264 frames** on one end (server), how would you go about making a real time (low latency) video stream viewable in browser (client) ?

In other words, what I'm trying to achieve is streaming graphically intensive c++ application from gpu server to browser.

As a simple solution, I'm thinking of something like this:

```
c++ app | ffmpeg | server | html5 client
```

h264 frames created by application are sent to standard output, where ffmpeg is used to remux this stream into mp4 that is passed to server, which upon request can pass it to client.

Is this a good approach ? Is that even possible to create a low latency 30fps video stream using this approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a right approach and possible thing to do.

Install Unreal Media Server and do RTMP publishing from ffmpeg to Unreal Media Server per http://umediaserver.net/umediaserver/faq.html

Then Unreal HTML5 player will play this stream near real-time, see examples at
http://umediaserver.net/umediaserver/demos.html